# Shell Script to find empty Hive databases

Tags: bash, shell, hive, sh

I am working on an audit process to delete empty Hive databases. I have a large number of databases that I need to go through and would like to use a shell script (.sh) in Linux that can run `hive -e` queries to identify empty databases and list them in some output file or log (wondering if a .txt file is an option?). I would then send this list to our admins to "drop" those empty databases.  All of our databases follow the exact same naming convention:  "environment" and "area" are always used... only "state" varies. >>> `environment_area_<state>`

Right now I am using the following queries to get the job done but it's very manual and very slow... I would end up spending a lot of time on the Linux command line.

I connect to Hive first in PuTTY, once connected, I run:

```sql
show databases;
use environment_area_<state>;
show tables;
```

If no tables show in the database, I add it to my list of databases that need to be deleted. I run the "use" and "show tables" queries over and over for every database.

As you can tell, this is a very time consuming approach and creating a shell script would really help.

I have searched online and watched a number of YouTube tutorials, but have not come across a use case that would help me out.  Hoping someone much more experienced with shell scripts could help me get beyond `#!/bin/bash` followed by the queries I listed above.

Comment: If you can provide output of full command, because I believe you write "show database" after connect to database, not to putty
also it would be good to provide hive output on your command with and without tables, it will help.

Comment: That you use PuTTY to connect to the database only reveals that you are using Windows locally. We would need to see how to connect to the database from Linux in your environment. (Maybe that's part of what the previous comment is trying to say.)

Comment: @Saboteur Not sure I understand what you mean by providing full output, but the steps I follow are 1) Open a PuTTy session and login into an EMR Edge Node (using my unique login credentials) 2) type "hive" ENTER to connect to Hive, and then I simply run the commands above. The results are a long list of all of the databases that currently exist; when I run "show tables" the results show any existing tables or if the database is empty, I simply get an "OK" result (indicating the query executed) but no tables listing because there are no tables.

Comment: @tripleee I think you're right.  I just responded to Saboteur's comment. I am launching a PuTTy session to an EMR Edge Node, then connect to Hive and run my commands directly from the command line.  The underlying files that feed any existing Hive tables sit in S3 for storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping hive answering commands in the background may improve performance significantly:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
# Cleanup at end of execution
trap 'rm -fr -- "$tempdir";exit' EXIT INT

hivein="$tempdir/hivein"
hiveout="$tempdir/hiveout"
mkfifo "$hivein" "$hiveout"

# Prepare file descriptors IO to talk to hive
exec 3<>"$hivein"
exec 4<>"$hiveout"

# Launch hive in the background
hive -S <&3 >&4 &

# Initialise hive
printf '%s\n' 'set hive.cli.print.header=false;' >&3

# Wait for hive response and get databases list
printf '%s\n' "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'environment_area_*';" >&3
mapfile -u 4 -t databases

empty_databases=()

for db in "${databases[@]}"; do
  printf 'USE %s; SHOW TABLES;\n' "$db" >&3
  mapfile -u 4 -t tables
  tbl_count="${#tables[@]}"
  printf 'Database %s contains %d tables.\n' "$db" "$tbl_count"

  if [ "$tbl_count" -eq 0 ]; then
    # record empty db
    empty_databases+=("$db")
  fi
done

# Close the hive-cli in case closing the file descriptors is not enough
printf '%s\n' '!exit' >&3

printf '%s\n' "${empty_databases[@]}" >empty_databases_list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with something you can modify this script. I did not check it. maybe `show tables` returns some header or extra newline, then modify script accordingly (`wc -l` counts newlines in output).

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for db in $(hive -S -e "show databases;") 
do
   tbl_count=$(hive -S -e "use $db; show tables;" | wc -l)
   echo "Database $db contains $tbl_count tables."
   
   if [ ${tbl_count} -eq 0 ]; then
     # Add db name to the file
     echo "$db" >> empty_databases_list.txt 
     # Do something else, for example drop db, etc
   fi
done
```

Comment: Database query tools often have options to disable headers and produce properly machine-readable output. Check the `hive` man page.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, `hive -S`  means silent mode, maybe additionally `set hive.cli.print.header=false;` should be added to each command, for example: `hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; show databases;"` I could not check how it works exactly because right now have no access to hive from shell and it will take a lot to start hadoop with hiive in a docker... I just provided the idea, OP will debug it themselves

Comment: Another good improvement would be launching `hive` only once in the background, throw commands at it through input file descriptor and read the results through its output file descriptor.

Comment: @leftjoin I tested two of the responses and both worked great.  Thanks for the help.  One question, you include `hive -S -e "show databases` but I actually ran `hive -e "show databases"` and that worked.  Can you provide insight in why -S is required? or what function it plays?  Thanks again

Comment: @Gdata0data0 -S means "silent mode", in silent mode hive does not print progress information. In case of such commands there is no progress information, this is why it works the same without -S. For queries triggering map-reduce jobs you need to use -S